# Component.onCompleted complains about "Non-existent attached object"

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML file `Foo.qml`:

```
import NDDView 1.0

NDDView {
    source: "nddcontent/Foo.uip"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("Yay!")
}
```

The `NDDView` component inherits from `QQuickFramebufferObject`. When I compile and use this component in my project, I get the error:

```
qrc:/Foo.qml:5 Non-existent attached object
```

- Why am I getting this error?
- How can I instead run 'setup' code on my component?

---

In case it matters, my real component looks more like this:

```
NDDView {
    property var    paths: ([])
    property int    items: 20
    property string prefix: "foo"
    Component.onCompleted: {
      for (var i=items;i--;) paths.push(prefix+i);
    }
}
```

I am trying to procedurally populate an array when the component is instantiated. If there's a better/alternate way to perform this task without `Component.onCompleted`, I'm happy to use it instead.

Comment: Import either `QtQml` or `QtQuick` to make the `Component` type available.

Comment: @jpnurmi That did it, thanks! Please post as an answer so that I can give you credit and rep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Component QML Type`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) type is registered by the [`QtQml`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html) module, and for backwards compatibility and convenience reasons, also by the [`QtQuick`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-index.html) module. In order to make the type available, you must import either of these modules. Therefore, when writing QML apps with Qt 5, most `.qml` files begin with either:

```
import QtQuick 2.0 // or later
```

or

```
import QtQml 2.0 // or later
```

The latest available version depends on which Qt version you are using, and how old Qt versions you want to support. Importing the latest version, which is documented in the beginning of each QML type, is necessary if you use properties or methods introduced in the latest version.